# Can I set max length of Text Area in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

```
                                    <cc1:xtextbox id="txtGroupDescription" maxlength="250" TextMode="Multiline" runat="server" cssclass="Required">
                                </cc1:xtextbox>
```

I have this code.When I run code and provides input grater than 250 programe terminated with "String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: Joking? Maxlength is the second parameter. Set it to a different value. Or do you get the error when you insert the data into a database?

Answer (score 0):

The error is triggered by the Data Base engine, if means a column is receiving more data that can it hold (maybe that nvarchar), in your code behind do this:

```
 txtGroupDescription.Text.Length>250 throw new exception("only 250 characters");
```

I'm pretty sure your column has 250 characters.